# Generated script of schema and table data not running in MS SERVER sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I have a very large table script that is about ^ GB in size and cannot open in in Query Editor (obviously) due to memory/size.

I am trying to run it on the db server with the command propmt and using sqlcmd:

[image]

I am 100% sure the path and script name are correct (marked out for privacy reasons). I then used the following two scripts to get the `DBServer\SQLInstance`:

```
SELECT @@servername

SELECT @@servicename
```

What am I missing as it appears it has not done anything with the 21? _ prompt just sitting there. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Did u set the serveroutput on similar setting for the db mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Windows command line pipeline is just choking on your previous command.

I think the best chance you have is doing this using PyPy:https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/, given the SQL instance has the memory to handle the data stream.